# Elevation API: Same coordinates, different elevation result

Tags: google-maps, elevation, api, google-elevation-api

I'm using google maps elevation API, but while asking a single request(single coordinates) and a multi-request(many coordinates), I'm getting different elevation result of the same latitude and longitude coordinates.

Any explanation please?

The result of the single request:

[image]

The result of the multi-request with the same lat and lng coordinates:

[image]

Comment: ok, i will copy my data. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single point request is returned with a finer resolution.

The [documentation for response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) says:

> Note that elevation data becomes more coarse (larger resolution
>   values) when multiple points are passed. To obtain the most accurate
>   elevation value for a point, it should be queried independently.